# Trouble getting a drupal 7 view template to render for a machine readable block

Tags: views, theming

i'm using drupal 7. I have created a content type called **Title and content navigation**.

I have setup a template override in **/sites/all/themes/themename/templates/views/title-and-content-navigation/block/views-view-fields--title-and-content-navigation.tpl.php** which works correctly for all of the displays which are blocks.

I have one of the displays for this view which has a machine readable name of **block_8**. I am trying to have a separate template file for this but I cannot work out what I need to name the file. I have tried many suggestions from SO and I can't get this to work. I have been flushing all caches. What to name the template files is very confusing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Theme: Information" under "Advanced" on the right hand side of the View edit page.

All the available template suggestions for the View and its displays are listed in the resulting modal.